# Insert Json data into SQL Server 2012 with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, json

I am parsing a data from a JSON link then I would like to insert it into one table in SQL Server 2012.
The parsing are working well, My only problem is the inserting of data into SQL Server.

Sample JSON Data:

```
"results": [   {
   "name": "The JPT Look On Do More - Commercial Transformation",
   "metrics": {
    "video": {
     "playthrough_75": "2981",
     "plays": "5466",
     "time_watched": "4030502288",
     "playthrough_100": "2288",
     "uniq_plays": {
      "monthly_uniqs": "4731",
      "daily_uniqs": "5136",
      "weekly_uniqs": "4991"
     },
```

Script:

```
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['results'] as $item)
{
$VideoName = $item['name'];
$playthrough_75 = $item['metrics']['video']['playthrough_75'];
$plays = $item['metrics']['video']['plays'];
$time_watched = $item['metrics']['video']['time_watched'];
$playthrough_100 = $item['metrics']['video']['playthrough_100'];
$plays_monthly_uniqs = $item['metrics']['video']['uniq_plays']['monthly_uniqs'];
$plays_daily_uniqs = $item['metrics']['video']['uniq_plays']['daily_uniqs'];
$plays_weekly_uniqs = $item['metrics']['video']['uniq_plays']['weekly_uniqs'];

$serverName = "SERVER_NAME";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"Web_Analytics");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

*INSERT SQL SCRIPT HERE* 
}
```

So from the script above, I stored each field into a variable and then What I would like to do is to execute this query below. How could I execute it using PHP?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Ooyala_Analytics([VideoName]
      ,[VideoId]
      ,[playthrough_75]
      ,[plays]
      ,[time_watched]
      ,[playthrough_100]
      ,[plays_monthly_uniqs]
      ,[plays_daily_uniqs]
      ,[plays_weekly_uniqs]
      ,)
      VALUES('$VideoName'
        ,'$VideoId'
        ,'$playthrough_75'
        ,'$plays'
        ,'$time_watched'
        ,'$playthrough_100'
        ,'$plays_monthly_uniqs'
        ,'$plays_daily_uniqs'
        ,'$plays_weekly_uniqs' 
        ')";
    }
```

Comment: You are quite unclear on what you want. Do you want to store the JSON file as it is? Then just put it (without decoding) simply in some NVARCHAR() field.
Or do you want to store all fields seperately in some table(s)? In that case just do the right inserts, each value to each field.
In case you are looking for real json support, wait for SQLServer 2016.
EDIT: And in case you don't know how to do an insert, ask another question. ;-)

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear, I'll edit my post. What I want is to put the Json result into one SQL Table.

Comment: What method are you using to connect to the database? Have you checked [PDO](http://php.net/manual/tr/ref.pdo-dblib.php) and [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)?

Comment: Haven't checked that yet, thanks for the link. I'll check that out

Comment: Thanks Seckin that article helped me.